# Does VB.NET have pattern matching like C# does?

Tags: vb.net, pattern-matching

Not too long ago C# added a nice "pattern matching" feature where you can check an object's type and cast it to that type all in one statement:

```
object o = GetSomeObjectFromTheDatabase();
if (o is Person p)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name} is {p.Age} years old.");
}
```

Does VB.NET have anything like this, or will I have to do the type check and cast in two separate operations as I have in the past?

Comment: No, VB has not added pattern matching.  (Notwithstanding the neglect to the language of late, I'm not even sure of how it would fit into the syntax if the goal were to add it; the pre-pattern-matching C# type matching syntax is much more straightforward to extend this way.)

Comment: @Craig  It shouldn't be so difficult to port something like `If TypeOf o Is Person` to `If TypeOf o Is Person p` or even to `If o Is Person p` (making `TypeOf` implicit). Someone has to do it, though...

Comment: @Jimi True, it's just that none of those fit aesthetically with the existing syntax.  Any could work, they just wouldn't really fit, that was kind of my point: except for the cast operators, everything involving putting a type on a variable involves `As`.  (Someone not only has to do it, they have to get it accepted, which actually seems like more of a barrier right now.)

Comment: Possibly only my opinion and failure of recall, but I seem to remember that MS have declared VB.NET to be "feature-complete", i.e. they won't be adding anything to it, and have invited the rest of the world to develop it by saying "it's open-source, *you* do it." Meanwhile, C# has to try to surpass whatever Java develops into or else we might as well use Java, which C# was meant to supplant. SO don't even bother including VB.NET in the languages used in their "developer survey". So... "C# added" != "VB.NET has/will have."

Comment: @Andrew Morton [Visual Basic support planned for .NET 5.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/visual-basic-support-planned-for-net-5-0/). The language is ported to the new platform, but no more updates to the language itself (at least, for now - not planned).

Comment: @Jimi I'm not sure if, for the future of VB.NET, that blog entry is bad, or worse. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Andrew Morton There are only good things in that post: 1. The language is very stable  2. *The future of Visual Basic [...] will focus on stability*, so even more stable :) 3. The language is very similar to C# :))

Comment: Thus, my comment about "which actually seems like more of a barrier right now."  It's theoretically possible that the language could move to an F# style of maintenance going forward (also see some of Anthony Green's recent blog posts), but it would require some openness on the part of MS to make it happen.

Comment: That having been said, the current feature state is a pretty good place to be.  There are very few of the newer C# features that seem like anything I'd be likely to use in my day-to-day VB work.  I'd feel differently if e.g. `Async/Await` were missing.

Comment: @Jimi That says 1) It's done. 2) We won't change it. 3) C# was meant to supplant Java, not VB. -- Dunno - that's the impression I've been given.

Comment: @Craig " It's theoretically possible that the language" - which "the" language, please?

Comment: @AndrewMorton VB.  Based on Anthony's comments, it seems that as of now, the only way there would be any forward movement with VB is an outright fork, vs. community development that would be folded into official releases.

Comment: @Craig Does that mean that the answer to the OP is "no", with the implication that further development efforts in VB.NET might be better invested in other languages?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I think we already long since answered OP's question, and the rest has been a digression on the present and future of VB.  I wouldn't give anybody particular advice on how they should direct their investments; they know better than I do what dev resources they have available.

Answer (score 2):

The `.TryCast` might be what you are looking for. If it succeeds, it will make the assignment, otherwise it returns Nothing. To test I just commented out one of the 2 `Return` statements.  Note that the underlying type is `Coffee` if `c` is returned.

```
Private Function GetSomeObjectFromTheDatabase() As Object
    Dim dt = LoadCoffeeTable() 'Returns a DataTable
    Dim c = New Coffee(CInt(dt(0)(0)), dt(0)(1).ToString, dt(0)(2).ToString)
    'Return c
    Return "I am not a Coffee"
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim o As Object = GetSomeObjectFromTheDatabase()
    Dim p As Coffee = TryCast(o, Coffee)

    If p Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Object is not a Coffee  " & o.ToString)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(p.Name)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As I had previously noted in my own comment (and Codexer noted in the previous answer), this feature is not in VB.

Based on recent comments from Microsoft (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/visual-basic-support-planned-for-net-5-0/) it doesn't seem likely that this feature will be added to the language in the near future.  That having been said, the language still has a very full set of features that is missing very little for day-to-day development.  If you're considering whether to do further development in VB, you would consider availability of development resources (internally and externally), suitability of VB for your project, and your current code base.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `VB` doesn't have pattern matching as mentioned already in the comments. One option is to create a module so we can create an extension to use on anything we would need to type match.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Extensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function IsPatternMatch(Of T)(MyObj As Object, ByRef outObj As T) As Boolean
        Dim isMatch As Boolean = TypeOf MyObj Is T
        outObj = If(isMatch, CType(MyObj, T), outObj)
        Return isMatch
    End Function

End Module
```

Example Usage:

```
 Dim o As Object = Nothing
 Dim p As Person = Nothing

 o = GetSomeObjectFromTheDatabase()
 If o.IsPatternMatch(p) Then
    ' Do something with p now...
 End If
```

Comment: Interesting. Though a bit obscure IMHO compared to `Dim p = TryCast(o, Person); If p IsNot Nothing Then ...` Which is virtually identical in length.